# How to find current page url (like "index.html")?

Tags: javascript, regex, window.location

With string `http://www.example.com/section_one/index.html` how can I return `index` using RegExp?
P.S.: Returning `index.html` is accepted too.

Comment: Sorry for dump question / duplicate, but I don't understand RegExp yet.

Comment: You want only regex? Will Javascript function to get value do?

Comment: this should work: `/([^\/]+?)\.html$/`

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky do you actually _want_ to use RegExp? You can do this without using a technology you don't understand. The browser comes with a `URL` object which can give get a URL and give you its various parts very easily without using any regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdf5rnvm/1/)

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/section_one/index.html";
var filename = url.match(/[^\\/]+$/)[0];
```

Comment: Did i understand the question correctly? He did ask for a RegExp right. Just trying to figure out why i was downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use regex for that. Its simple:

```
var url = document.URL;
var currentPage= url.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: He is asking for a regex solution, your answer works, but regex is a lot faster

Comment: This will return `index.html` user wants just `index`. and user wants regex.

Comment: So what if the user wants a regex, user wants a solution. This is only wrong because of the `.html` part. Also - @Michiel I call bullshit on the speed claim.

Comment: Can you see the question title before downvoting...He said he wants current page URL like ("index.html")

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks, I'm repeating something I heard I should have checked.

Comment: @Hammad I don't know why you were downvoted but this sort of thing is why while I'm writing a proposal for JavaScript's RegExp object I avoid answering these questions. We have a cultural problem with this tag.

Comment: I shortened it a little. It's still off-topic (the real answer would be `.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]`) but at least it doesn't pollute the scope.